# Bootstrap's thumbnail not centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4 offset2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/images/johndoe.jpg" />
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">John Doe</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/images/johnsmith.jpg" />
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">John Smith</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There are 12 columns logically and they are allocated by `.span*` classes. I have two thumbnails which have `.span4` class. This means they can be shown side-by-side if there is enough width on device. I want those two thumbnails to be shown in center. So I add `.offset2` class to the first one in order to shift them 2 columns. Consequently, they should be seen in the center but they are still aligned to the left.

I see that the rule `margin-left: 180px;` in `.offset2` is ignored. Because there is `margin-left: 20px;` in `thumbnails > li` which overrides `.offset2`'s rule.

How can I get rid of this conflict?

Comment: You should rewrite the question in a shape where you're asking how to override the bootstrap classes. Asking *why* bootstrap was designed the way it was designed is quite a subjective question (except if a bootstrap developer drops by)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Added one more class to `ul`

```
<ul class="thumbnails centerThumb">
```

CSS

```
.centerThumb .span4 {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.centerThumb {
  text-align: center
}
```

Check this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/caoAb)

Comment: I think the op will loose the bootstrap styling "thumbnails" provides. The problem is with the span* classes being on thumbnail `li`'s in the first place.

Comment: ohh!!! did not thought of that, I have updated my answer. Thanks for bringing that in notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this your thumbnails will be in  center 

 <ul class="thumbnails row col-lg-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-8">
        <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="/images/johndoe.jpg" />
                <h4 style="text-align: center;">John Doe</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="/images/johnsmith.jpg" />
                <h4 style="text-align: center;">John Smith</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
css

li{
    list-style:none;
}
.thumbnails{
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle link for your reference](http://jsfiddle.net/francisstalin/nELsq/)